# Postgres column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to fix a query to make it both oracle and postgres compatible. But the same query works in oracle not in postgres. The example query is simplied and doesn't have real meaning but it is a good example to show the problem I'm trying to solve.

Postgres version: 11.2, oracle version: 12.1.0.2.0

Payments table has two columns (payment_id, amount);

Users Table has one column (user_id);

Query 1:

```
select p.amount, (select min(p.payment_id) from payments, users where p.payment_id = payments.payment_id) 
from payments p, users;
```

Error in postgres: 
column "p.amount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Query 2:

```
select (select min(p.payment_id) from payments, users where p.payment_id = payments.payment_id) from payments p, users;
```

Error in postgres:
subquery uses ungrouped column "p.payment_id" from outer query

Does anyone know why the above two queries work in oracle but not in postgres?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your sample queries don't even return the same columns, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: *The example query is simplied and doesn't have real meaning* ... please post exact or near exact as actual.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the data in payments ordered correctly but this will remove duplicate payment_id observations:

select a.user_id, a.payment_id, b.amount
from users a
    inner join (select distinct on (payment_id) payment_id, amount from payments) b
        on a.payment_id = b.payment_id
;